# Correct way of using Vollkorn for both text and math

Tags: fontspec, fourier

I'm trying to use [Vollkorn](http://vollkorn-typeface.com/) typeface for both text and math. I want Greek letters to be italic in math mode and to use Vollkorn. In addition I need some symbols from fourier package. I have tried this:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}

    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[BoldFont=Vollkorn Medium, BoldItalicFont=Vollkorn Medium Italic, Numbers={Proportional,Uppercase}]{Vollkorn}
    \setsansfont[]{Droid Sans}
    \usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes,noendash]{mathastext}

    \begin{document}
    The brace does not scale properly if I use fourier package. Greek letters are not using Vollkorn font and are not italic.
    \begin{equation}
        a = 
        \begin{cases}
            x \\
            y
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \left(\left \lbrace \Gamma^{(5)}\right\rbrace\right)^3
    \end{equation}
    I only need some of the symbols from fourier package like $\mathbb{S}$ and $\mathcal{F}$.

    \end{document}
```

but it does not work as intended. [image: Result using XeLatex]

I'm using XeLatex to compile. What is the correct way of changing the font to Vollkorn?

Comment: For the Greek letters please suggest a good replacement until Vollkorn adds polytonic greek and for completeness how to use them when they become available.

Comment: Libertine math may have similar serif weights.

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the Vollkorn typeface site, there is no Vollkorn Math nor Vollkorn Greek support. So you will have to choose some fitting Math Font, maybe Euler Math (alternatively, you can try to approach the Greek Capital Gamma as a Cyrillic Capital G).

EDIT: Reinspecting the Vollkorn site, there is now Greek and Math support available in the fonts. I have not checked how complete it is from a TeX point of view, but it is there, at least.

Comment: You are right, thanks. The problem with the braces is still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the Vollkorn fonts -- as of version 4.105 (may 2018) -- are available in OTF and TTF formats. They will work out of the box with `xelatex` and `lualatex`.  Some Math symbols are available in the text fonts, but the Vollkorn bundle *does not* provide any Math font.

Using `mathastext` with `xelatex` (or `lualatex`) is *not* an option, you could try `mathspec` instead (with `xelatex`), but do not expect a very good output: digits and letters will be borrowed from Vollkorn fonts, but symbols would be from CMR fonts.

My advice: choose from the available Unicode (OpenType) Math fonts one which more or less matches the Vollkorn text fonts --- you can find about twenty examples of free Math fonts at the end of file https://daniel.flipo.free.fr/doc/luatex/pdf2lua.pdf ---.  Then, you will be able to pick up some symbols (mathbb, mathcal) from any other Unicode Math font using the `range=` option (see the unicode-math documentation).