# LuaLaTeX, Vollkorn and Math Symbols

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, math-fonts

A similar question was asked a few years ago [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290548/correct-way-of-using-vollkorn-for-both-text-and-math) but since then, Vollkorn claims to have included support for a variety of math symbols, greek letters, and others. I have tried to use the .otf files as available on the Vollkorn [website](http://vollkorn-typeface.com/), and since there is no -math.otf file in the collection, I thought the symbols would be included in the regular or italic font file. When running the code below, however, it gives a warning from unicode-math saying there is no script "Math" and the equation appears to be using the default font.

Am I misunderstanding how math fonts are made accessible and is there something else I have to do to make it work? Or am I mistaken in thinking that the math symbols provided by Vollkorn are sufficient?

MWE here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = Vollkorn-Bold,
    ItalicFont = Vollkorn-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = Vollkorn-BoldItalic,
    UprightFont = Vollkorn-Regular,
    ]
\setmathfont{Vollkorn-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello}
        {\LaTeX} World!
        
        A simple equation \textit{aVar dVar}
        \begin{equation}
            \alpha = \int_{0}^{\infty} aVar dVar 
        \end{equation}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not (just) about the symbols being available, Opentype math fonts need additional metadata in the font file. Vollkorn doesn't provide this (which fontspec is trying to tell you with the "no script Math" warning), so it can't be used with unicode-math.

Comment: Maybe look at the mathspec package instead of unicode-math IIRC that attempts to use textfonts for maths.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, Mathspec doesn't work for me because I'm working in LuaLaTeX but the similar mathastext gets close, I'll play around with it more.

Comment: Is there a place I can learn more about the required metadata and how to add it to a font? I haven't been able to find anything useful on that

Comment: Oh, I messed that `mathspec` doesn't support LuaTeX. The "required metadata" is mostly the Opentype MATH table It is specified [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/math) and consists of >50 font level constants + some per glyph information (mostly italic correction and accent placement, but also data for extensible delimiters and index staircase kerning) + some OpenType features related to script sizes etc. You might also want to look at the articles about the "TeX Gyre Math" project at http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/math/index_html .

Comment: This can be edited e.g. with fontforge (https://fontforge.org/docs/ui/dialogs/math.html) Of course this needs all glyphs o be present irst (including not just the operators, but also all required math alphabets [especially the "Math Alphanumeric Symbols" block (https://codepoints.net/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols)] and all required sizes of extensible delimiters / components for growing delimiters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating the paths suggested in the comments by Marcel Krüger I came across the package [mathfont](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathfont) which provides a lot of the same behaviour as [mathspec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) but is accessible to LuaLaTeX users, and worked better for me than [mathastext](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext). For mathfont however it seems that the fonts must be installed to the system.

[image: Vollkorn math symbols demo]

So I was able to get the above from this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[Vollkorn]{mathfont}
\setmainfont{Vollkorn}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    ]
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    detect-all,
    detect-family = true,
    per-mode = reciprocal
}%

\begin{document}
    \section{Hello}
        {\LaTeX} World!
        
        A simple equation aVar dVar \textit{aVar dVar}
        \begin{equation}
            \alpha = \left\{\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\oint_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{V_{t}}{\gamma}\right]}{\iint_{0}^{\infty}\Delta}\right)\right\} \mathrm{d}\gamma
        \end{equation}

        This means then that $\beta >\SI{10}{\kilo\volt}$
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite interesting package!

Comment: `mathspec` can also be made to work with LuaTeX.  I should maybe submit my patches.

Comment: I think that would be great, mathspec seems like the ideal solution